# Xamarin.Android error - 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform'

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have searched for a solution, to no avail. I am trying to build a Xamarin.Android project but i keep getting the error detailed below. I Am running Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition in Windows 10.
Compiler Output:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "Aapt" task failed unexpectedly. System.AggregateException:
>   One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not
>   a valid application for this OS platform.    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.RunAapt(String commandLine)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.ExecuteForAbi(String cmd, String
>   currentResourceOutputFile)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.DoExecute(ITaskItem manifestFile,
>   ParallelLoopState state, Int32 loop)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass30_02.b__3(Int32
>   i, ParallelLoopState state, TLocal local)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_01.b__1()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object
>   )    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive,
>   Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action 1 body,
>   Action 2 bodyWithState, Func 4 bodyWithLocal, Func 1 localInit,
>   Action 1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](TSource[]
>   array, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action 1 body, Action 2
>   bodyWithState, Action 3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func 4
>   bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func 5 bodyWithEverything, Func 1 localInit,
>   Action 1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable 1
>   source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action 1 body, Action 2
>   bodyWithState, Action 3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func 4
>   bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func 5 bodyWithEverything, Func 1 localInit,
>   Action 1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable1
>   source, Func1 localInit, Func 4 body, Action1 localFinally)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for
>   this OS platform.    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.RunAapt(String commandLine)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.ExecuteForAbi(String cmd, String
>   currentResourceOutputFile)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.DoExecute(ITaskItem manifestFile,
>   ParallelLoopState state, Int32 loop)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass30_02.b__3(Int32
>   i, ParallelLoopState state, TLocal local)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_01.b__1()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object
>   )<--- LetsLend.Android

Comment: Do you have a valid/non-corrupted android-sdk installed? Try manually executing `aapt.exe` on the cmd line. It will be located within the your android SDK install location, in a subdirectory `build-tools\XX.X.X\aapt.exe` (If your SDK is update to date, `XX.X.X` will be `27.0.0`)

Comment: Wow, thats's exactly what the problem was. I navigated to the "build-tools" subdirectory and realized that "aapt.exe" was 0KB in size. I re-downloaded the build-tools via the Android SDK Manager and now all is good. (Not sure how to mark this as the answer but it is the answer)

Answer (score 0):

> "Aapt" task failed
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

Check if you have a valid/non-corrupted Android SDK `aapt.exe` / `aapt`  installed.

1) Locate the Android SDK root directory location that Visual Studio is using:

- Mac:

[image]

- Windows:

[image]

Open a shell and `cd` into your root Android SDK directory and try manually executing `aapt.exe` / `aapt`.

Note: It will be located within in a subdirectory `build-tools\XX.X.X` (Currenty `XX.X.X` will be `27.0.0` if your SDK is update to date)

If `aapt` is valid it will output all of its usages options, otherwise open the Android SDK Manager and uninstall / re-install the latest version of the **Build Tools**

[image]