# Android emulator error: "Device error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid..."

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator

Android emulators worked fine for a long time till today.  I suddenly started getting the following error:

```
Device error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Xamarin.DeviceManager.Common.EmulatorManager.<>c__DisplayClass61_0.<StartProcess>b__0()
```

[image]

I checked [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064105/xamarin-android-error-the-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-application-for) and tried its solution.  aapt.exe in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\28.0.3" is fine. 
I have rebooted Visual Studio and restarted my PC to no avail.
I am wondering if anyone could offer a tip on how to remedy this.

Comment: ,You can try to click one emulator, then clicking Edit, to change the firstly property, change 800M as 4000M, then try again.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Thank you for the tip.  I will try it next time.  I went to Android SDKs and Tools and tried to reinstall something, but it asked me to do a repair, and I did, then the emulators started working.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue, thank for sharing your solution here.